# Front chain rings don't shift properly after installing a bottom bracket and shorter spindles

Tags: bottom-bracket, derailleur-front

My problem is I fitted shorter spindles and a new bottom bracket now front gears are not working as they should, the chain on the third click should be on the outer sprocket but only goes to the middle, or if you go the other way after two clicks the chain comes off.

Comment: Are you sure the bottom bracket is compatible with your previous one? Are you sure you installed it correctly? If you installed a shorter spindle, all else being equal, I would expect the chain to fall off of the larger chainring side, not of the smaller

Comment: What was the reason for choosing a shorter spindle?  Was it the only option available?  I'd be concerned about the chainline now being off.

Answer (score 4):

You need now to re-adjust your front deraileur.

By installing a spindle of different length (and possibly a different bottom bracket), you changed the relative position of your chainrings in relation to the front deraileur.

Here is a instructional video:
[Park Tools - How to Adjust a Front Derailleur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNG7g83lI-s)

Answer (score 0):

What’s the difference in length? If it's couple mm lets say around 5mm you should be able to adjust limit screws on your derailleur, possibly cable tension as well.